# replacing 1fr for 100% in CSS grid

Tags: html, css

I am creating a new layout and having troubles with 100% value so my question is:

Is there another way to replace the 1fr value for something else than 100%?

See the example below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav main aside" "footer footer footer";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; /* is this necessary ? */
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr 220px; /* here */
  grid-template-rows: 133px 1fr 50px; /* and here */
  grid-gap: 0;
}
```

I changed it to 100% like this `250px 100% 220px;` but it gives error, the middle part goes actually bigger than 100% and makes the first and third div to be smaller...

I want the design for desktop only (no other devices accepted)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Yes it will blow out the grid because you are asking that row to be 100% the size of `.container`. There is nothing that will replace 1fr, which is a calculation meaning 100% of the *leftover space*, but you can approximate it by making all the track sizes percentages which add up to 100. You should provide more detail about what you're trying to achieve for a more specific answer.

Comment: You could use `calc(100% - 250px - 220px)` (or just `calc(100% - 470px)`), but it seems kind of silly to do a calculation that CSS will do for you.

Comment: So you mean 1fr is the result of this calculation? Dreamweaver show error in code when I let the 1fr be thats why I wanted to change it

Comment: 1fr is correct you can keep it even if you get error. Many tools are still not up to date to recognize new CSS values